# Is it appropriate to use Document in the react framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component. Which renders a simple HTML. I have an event handler attached to an element. On clicking that particular element I want some CSS styles to change. For that I used the code below-

```
import React from 'react';
import './start.css';

class Start extends React.Component {
    handleEvent() {
        const login = document.querySelector('.login');
        const start = document.querySelector('.start')
        login.style.right = '0';
        start.style.left = '-100vw';
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section className = 'page start'> 
               <h1>Welcome To Our App</h1>
               <button onClick = {this.handleEvent}>Next</button>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Start;
```

My question is in the `handleEvent()` is it appropriate to select the elements using Document and style the elements using `.style`. Is there any other "react-specific" way to do this?

Comment: I guess the "react-specific" way would be to store state with `{right:0, left:-100vw}`, and have this reflect in the  component's`style={right:this.state.right, left:this.state.left}` in `render()`, and then just setting `setState()` in `handleEvent()`, and having render do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
         super();

         this.state = {
              black: true
         }
    }

    changeColor(){
        this.setState({black: !this.state.black})
    }

    render(){
        let btn_class = this.state.black ? "blackButton" : "whiteButton";

        return (
             <div>
                 <button className={btn_class}
                         onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
                           Button
                  </button>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blackButton{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.whiteButton{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

first of all yes you can use document in react for that. But "react specific" style you be something like this:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

In css file :

```
button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.blackButton{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.whiteButton{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

and finally a component :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
         super();

         this.state = {
              black: true
         }
    }

    changeColor(){
        this.setState({black: !this.state.black})
    }

    render(){
        let btn_class = this.state.black ? "blackButton" : "whiteButton";

        return (
             <div>
                 <button className={btn_class}
                         onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
                           Button
                  </button>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a state to check whether the button has been clicked and change the class name

Similar approach can be used.

This is the React Specific way!

You can refer to React doc
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

```
import React from 'react';
import './start.css';

class Start extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hasButtonClicked : false};
  }
    handleEvent() {
 this.setState({hasButtonClicked : true});
    }
    render() {
        let clicked = this.state.hasButtonClicked;
        return (
            <section className = { clicked ? someCssClass :'page start'} > 
               <h1>Welcome To Our App</h1>
               <button onClick = {this.handleEvent}>Next</button>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```